# Felix Bundle has lots of wrong imports

Tags: maven, osgi

I am very confused by the felix-bundle plugin. The documentation says of the Import-Package tag

> This header rarely has to be explicitly specified. However, in certain cases when there is an unwanted import, such an import can be removed by using a negation package pattern

But I am building a plugin and it seems to be importing lots of things that I don't want. javax.servlet is going in, as are junit.* and org.junit.*, and org.testng, and some apache logging packages. All of these are making my package crash in use with a missing requirement error.

The thing is, I have no idea why these are getting included in the first place. Very confused. Help welcome.

In response to an answer, AFAIK, I am not using javax.servlet anywhere in my code. My POM currently looks like this. I've had to exclude lots of packages which are otherwise breaking the load.

All turning out to be a bit of a nightmare!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
      <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
      <version>7</version>
    </parent>



        <groupId>uk.org.russet</groupId>
    <artifactId>uk.org.russet.protege.nrepl-clojure</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>protege-nrepl</name> 
    <description>Provide an NREPL client to use Clojure inside Protege</description>

    <packaging>bundle</packaging>


    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.russet</groupId>
            <artifactId>nrepl-clojure</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
          </dependency>

      <!--dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.protege.common</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-beta-05-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency-->

          <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.protege.editor.core.application</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-beta-05-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.protege.editor.owl</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-beta-05-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.7</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
        <instructions>
          <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
          <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId};singleton:=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          <Bundle-Vendor>The Protege Development Team</Bundle-Vendor>
          <Import-Package>
                    !javax.servlet*,!junit.*,!org.junit*,!org.apache.*,
                    !org.testng.*,!sun.misc.*,org.protege.editor.*,
                    org.protege.editor.core,org.protege.editor.core.ui.workspace,
                    org.protege.editor.owl.model,org.protege.editor.core.editorkit,
                    org.semanticweb.owlapi.model, *
          </Import-Package>
          <Include-Resource>plugin.xml, {maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
                  <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                  <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>
        </instructions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>    
              <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>   
          </execution>
        </executions>
          </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.9</version>
              <configuration>
                <pde>true</pde>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are added because some code inside your bundle uses those packages. For example if any of your code uses `javax.servlet` then the bundle will necessarily import `javax.servlet`. So this import at least seems reasonable.

The imports of testing libraries do not seem so reasonable, of course. It suggests that your tests have been included in your bundle alongside the "real" classes, which should not happen. Do you keep your tests in the same source folder as the real classes? It's normal and recommended practice to write test code in a separate source folder; in Maven this is usually `src/test/java`.

If that's not the case then you should show the configuration you have used.

Comment: If I were using javax.servlet I would understand, but as far as I can tell, I am not.

Comment: Thanks for posting the config. I suspect it's something to do with your use of `Embed-Dependency` and `Embed-Transitive`. This literally pulls in all of your build dependencies, including the transitive ones, into your bundle. The plugin then does inspection of all the .class files in all those libraries and works out the dependencies. It's no surprise therefore to find you have a large number of dependencies being generated.

Comment: If I don't put this, then my bundle doesn't get dependencies and my code also fails. I've grep'd through the listings for all the jars included. None of them have junit, none of them javax.servlet. It's very, very strange. I have no idea where they are coming from!

Comment: How do you mean, the listings? Do you mean the content listings (which would not contain `javax.servlet` etc, in fact this is exactly the problem)? Or do you mean the source code listings for all the JARs? Why not take all these dependencies and deploy them as OSGi bundles rather than building a single gigantic bundle?

Comment: Listings as in `jar -t`. Deploying all the dependencies as OSGi bundles (of which there are 32, one of which I control) would be a very heavy-weight thing to do, especially if I have to go to this effort to declare the dependencies between them. And quite a few of are involved in dynamically loading dependencies into the classpath. Sounds like a life time of pain. I think I have got to the point where debugging the plugin, or just living with it seems the thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think this answers the question. There is no need to debug the plugin, it is doing the right thing. At least one of the many classes in these JARs depends on `javax.servlet`, but as you said the JAR does not contain `javax.servlet`, therefore it becomes a dependency and must be imported with `Import-Package`. Likewise one or more JARs must contain tests that depend on JUnit etc, so you have a dependency on JUnit packages.

Comment: That's possible, but I am also getting packages in sun.* packages and many other places. I can believe these are in the classpath when running, but I doubt they are dependencies of the code. The plugin clearly isn't doing the right thing, because the bundles crash when loaded, complaining about missing wiring. Regardless, I have something working now, so I think I am going to stop worrying about what the plugin is doing!

Comment: I still assert the plugin is doing the right thing. Many libraries have junk dependencies in them, I see it all the time.

Comment: It's behaving in a way which results in a non-functional build. The documentation says "in certain cases" you get unwanted imports, but says no more. Granted that a maven plugin with incomplete documentation is hardly rare, but this is less than ideal.

Comment: So will many tools if you misuse them. Garbage in, garbage out. What's missing from the documentation?